# If I have a truth table, is there a way of determining the bitwise expression I need for that truth table?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I am attempting to do the following in c:

```
unsigned int mask;
unsigned int previous;
unsigned int new;
unsigned int out;

for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
{
    bool bit_set = GET_BIT( mask, i );

    // If the mask bit is true, use the new bit, otherwise use the previous bit
    SET_BIT( out, i, GET_BIT( bit_set ? new : previous, i ) );
}
```

However I think there may be an easier and quicker way using bitwise operations. I have the truth table but I don't know how to get the expression I need.

Truth table is:

```
m | p | n | o
0 | 0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0 | 0
0 | 0 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 1 | 1
0 | 1 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

How would I go about working this out?

Comment: in future questions , you should write the truth table in numeric order and write what are the inputs and what is the output.(I.E it seems that m,p,n are the inputs but dasblinkenlight below understood that all are inputs...) - P.S if m,p,n are the inputs the logic expression is very easy

Comment: @Gil.I m, p, n, o are "mask", "previous", "new", "out" from the example code.

Comment: They do map to the variables I used, but yes its a bit non obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) - there is a [solver](http://www.ee.calpoly.edu/media/uploads/resources/KarnaughExplorer_1.html) available online. Pick "three values", enter the expected results for all eight combinations, and use the expression the solver produces:

```
F(m, p, n) = (p & !n) | (m & n)
```

**EDIT :** You can expand this solution to do the whole byte at once, rather than doing it one bit at a time, by using the `~` bitwise NOT operator:

```
result = (mask & new) | (~mask & previous);
```

Comment: nit - he should pick three variables, not four (`o` depends on `mnp`).  Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @JohnBode Oops, I misinterpreted the truth table: I thought that the last column was the input #4, and the table listed all rows where the output is `1` :) This is now fixed, thank you very much!

Comment: The || and && should be | and &, the question is about bit-wise operators. Also, I think the answer should be p & !m | m & n, seems there is an 'a' in there that is wrong.

Comment: @tengfred You're right, the solver does not let you rename variables, solving `F(A,B,C)`.

Comment: To be honest I think the question title is misleading - it's not really about getting bitwise (or boolean) expressions from truth tables at all. The questioner has a particular condition, which does have a particular truth table associated with it, which you may or may not need to use to come up with a suitable expression...

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks, I think I finally understood why `M, N, O, and P` from the alphabet are listed in that peculiar order!

Comment: I had a friend at school, supported a team called Queens Park Rangers. Typical thing for him to write when doing vector operations: `(x,y,z) + (q,p,r) = (x+q,y+p,z+r)`. True but deeply confusing.

Comment: I see what you mean, I should have put the output at the beginning. Should I edit my question that way?

Comment: @yuumei No, that's OK - in fact, the truth table is not necessary, because you "spelled out" the logic in the body of your program.

Answer (score 3):

> If the mask bit is true, use the new bit, otherwise use the previous
>   bit

The natural way to express this (to me) is `(mask & new) | (~mask & previous)`. That is to say, mask corresponding bits from `new` and `previous`, and add them together using OR.

Comment: Did you mean to use the bitwise NOT operator `~` instead of  logical negation `!`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: very much so.